# How do you name rails routes based on a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a model named City (its table being cities, and the Controller being Cities). I want to dynamically create routes for each of the cities in the table. I also would like for the city name to be the first part of the url. So for example, I would like the url to say:

```
mywebsite.com/seattle
```

and not

```
mywebsite.com/cities/seattle
```

There will be many cities within the table, and they might be created or deleted. Does anyone know how I might set up the routes for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards in your url to set this up.  In your `config/routes.rb` put:

```
get '/:city', to: 'cities#show'
```

And then you can access the wildcard element in your show method with

```
params[:city]
```

for example

```
def show
  @city = City.find_by_name(params[:city])
end
```

Comment: Also remember that, to avoid messing with all your other routes, this rule must be the last one in your routes file.